# Hide Sub Report for first record

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

In have a main report in which for the same name we have two records as we have two dates related to that query and we get two rows.
I have an Applicant whose information is being displayed and I have a sub report which is linked to the main report Applicant name so it is being shown for each Applicant(in a way I wanted).

But I want to show sub report only for the second row of the same applicant, not for both the rows as sub report has a simple detail of the Applicant and it looks vague when it shows same data fro first row as well as second row.

Is there any way I achieve this?

```
Applicant     City     Date
 A            City1   2012/01/01
Subreport:
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 A            City1   2011/01/01
Subreport:
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

And I want display like:

Applicant     City     Date
 A            City1   2012/01/01
 A            City1   2011/01/01
Subreport:
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done now, is I added a Running Total field under my group, it gave record number for each row within group, how to do that you can see here:
[Setting Record Number under Each Group](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/76847.aspx)

Now I set the supress formula for the section containing sub report like of

```
if RunningTotalField>1 then True
```

In this way when we have more than one record in the same group, in my case I will only have one Applicant in Group(so it worked here), Then it is going to hide the second subreport.